# How can I fix Firefox's jagged scrolling on Lion?

Tags: performance, firefox, macos

I noticed that scrolling in Firefox on Lion is not very pleasant experience.

Is there a way to optimize it for better performance?

I tried smooth scrolling setting - but it didn't do anything.

Comment: How are you scrolling? I use FireFox, on 4GB iMac with Magic mouse, no problems.

Comment: I use built in track-pad

Comment: Works fine for me: Mac Air trackpad, 10.7.4, FF 15.0.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to configuration by type `about:config` in address bar and press enter key then enter scroll in filter box, now you can change all scroll options.